# Are there any tech limitations for connecting client side (browser) javascript to a remote mysql server?

Tags: javascript, mysql, tcpclient

I am exploring the idea of connecting a client side web application directly to a mysql server.

I can not use a backend web application as a proxy, and I can't use the mysql http plugin.

From a brief research on the web, it seems that the general agreement is that it can not be done or it should not be attempted.

Are there any technological limitations for this? MySql is listening on a network port, and should not care what kind of client is connecting to it. Why can't the client be written in pure javascript that can run on the browser? Can I write javascript code that connects to a TCP socket and sends data to it as any other mysql gui?

Just interested if I should explore this idea further?

Comment: If you somehow made this work (impossible in any modern browser for security reasons - allowing client side connections to arbitrary IPs and ports is a nightmare to imagine), all of your clients will have the credentials to read/write your database at will.

Comment: Also why don't you have the ability to use a backend server side program?  Surely you could host a Java or PHP webapp in the cloud somewhere?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have a client that has a machine in an company intranet with no access to the internet. It has to be something that runs on his machine. He wants a small apllication that will connect to the mysql execute some queries and get back results. It is really a simple project so I was thinking a desktop app in Qt, but I am not that familiar with Qt, so I was exploring the possibility to do it as a web application that can be called by double clicking a HTML file. I could install XAMP on his machine, but it would be a complication.

Comment: You could possibly do a deployable nodejs webapp.

Comment: @CollinD, interesting did not know that something like that was possible. Will explore it

Comment: why the down votes and the close votes? I am not saying it is a good idea to do it, but I am asking why is it a bad idea or why is it not possible?

Comment: well, maybe because it does not show research (apart from "brief research" souding a bit.. brief, there is also no linking and or quoting from this 'research', so the question content is not helped at all by this research). That's one of the mentioned "-1" reasons if you read the mouse-over. Then, the question itself seems to be `Just interested if I should explore this idea further?`. That doesn't sound as a 'usefull' question, and will not help future people at all. So yeah, you can go all "ow, misanthropic geeks", or you could actually think about if the question is a good fit here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Electron to create a desktop app in Javascript/HTML/CSS:
http://electron.atom.io

Then, use the native mysql node.js module from NPM to connect to the server, while following the requirements from Electron for using native node modules:
http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/

Answer (score 1):

You can't. MySQL only accepts connections from clients speaking the MySQL network protocol, and Javascript running in the web browser can only make HTTP connections. (If you're wondering about WebSockets, those are a subset of HTTP -- they can't be used to make arbitrary network connections.)

In any case, if you just want to store data locally in a Javascript web application, you don't need MySQL. You can store data directly in the browser using the [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).